# How can I make my program input images taken from a Camera?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am working on a python program that reads license plates from trucks. An image that gets processed by this program and filters the characters as output. Here is the input of the image in the program:

```
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg') #variable 'img' gets processed later using ocr
```

Now, is there a way I can make a webcam for instance: take an image, store it somewhere, and **run the program with the taken image?**

Using Python 3.7.2

Comment: check out [cv2.VideoCapture](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture a single frame by using the [VideoCapture](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html) method of OpenCV.

```
import cv2

pic = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # video capture source camera (Here webcam of laptop) 
ret,frame = pic.read() # return a single frame in variable `frame`

while(True):
    cv2.imshow('img1',frame) #display the captured image
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('y'): #save on pressing 'y' 
        cv2.imwrite('images/c1.png',frame)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break

pic.release()
```

Comment: you can replace the same img and read it

Comment: Please do not use the comments space for adding info; edit & update your post instead.

Answer (score 0):

for camera/video i can recommand this [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # if frame is read correctly ret is True
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

`cv.VideoCapture(0)` capture the video frames and `ret, frame = cap.read()` read each frame